# How to change order of the subsites in the dropdown?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, dropdown

I created a 5 subsites under a team site and enabled show subsites option. So We can the subsites in a dropdown. They are automatically arranged in alphabetical order. How can I change that order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the level where you have the site that has subsites go to:

- Site Settings --> under Look and Feel choose "Navigation". The attached picture should explain the rest. Just make sure to have the feature Sharepoint Server Publishing Infrastructure at site collection level activated and you're good to go.[image]